# Overloading addition function and the result creates a new type of class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, operator-overloading, overloading

I need to overload the addition function so that it takes in the first point and the end point as the left and right side of the equation and outputs the equation. This is what my code looks right now. I'm not sure how to involve the line class?

```
import math
class Point:
    '''Class that creates points. Attributes: Eastings and Northings'''
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.eastings = x
        self.northings = y
    def getCoords(self):
        self.coords = (self.eastings,self.northings)
        return self.coords
    def setCoords(self,other_x,other_y):
        self.eastings = float(other_x)
        self.northings = float(other_y)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.eastings},{self.northings}"
    def __add__(self,new_point):
        pass
        #creates a line (new class)


class Line(Point):
    '''Class that creates line object based on two points'''
    def __init__(self,start,end):
        self.start = start #Type:Point (x1,y1)
        self.end = end #Type:Point (x2,y2)
        self.latitude = abs(self.end.eastings - self.start.eastings)
        self.departure = abs(self.end.northings - self.start.northings)
        self.distance = math.sqrt((self.latitude)**2 + (self.departure)**2)
        self.azimuth = math.degrees(math.atan2(self.departure,self.latitude))
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        if key == 0:
            ans = self.start
        elif key == 1:
            ans = self.end
        else:
            print("invalid index")
        return ans

#test code
a = Point(0,0)
b = Point(1,1)
c = Point(1,0.5)

line1 = a+b
print((type(line1))
```

The test code is supposed to print out the type as class line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a `self.getCoords()` call to your `Point.__init__()` method.
2. Add `return Line(self, new_point)` to your `Point.__add__()` method.

Testing:

```
a = Point(0,0)
b = Point(1,1)
c = Point(1,0.5)

line1 = a+b
print(type(line1)) # I have removed a round bracket on the left
```

Output: `<class '__main__.Line'>`

In case you want to run a block of code, where a function/method has not one line in it, you have to add a `pass` to it. Otherwise you will get an error, because the structure requires it. Or you comment the function declaration out.

Comment: How should I add `self.getCoords()` ? Just as an attribute? So far I added the second part of this to the addition method and it works.

Comment: @rilke-nz You do not have to do it, but I would recommend removing the `getCoords()` method and adding `self.coords = (self.eastings,self.northings)` to your `setCoords()` method. Then you add `self.coords = (self.eastings,self.northings)` to your `__init__()` method. In case you want to access `self.coords` from the outside, you can do that without a method e. g. : `print(a.coords)` prints the coordinates of your Point a. In case you change the coordinates with `setCoords()`, `self.coords` would be changed automatically.

Comment: @rilke-nz Sorry, I did not really pay attention. You can remove every line from your `Point.__init__()` method and then you can add `self.setCoords(x, y)`.  (2 lines less)

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing that says the `__add__()` method has to return a the same type as the instance — which means you could this:

```
class Point:
    ...
    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Point):
            return Line(self, other)  # Line from this Point to the other.
        else:
            raise TypeError(f"Can't add a non-Point to a Point}")
```

Be careful doing this however, because the `Line` class will inherit the method (so you probably need to modify its version of it).

Comment: I think the OP wants two real Points given to the Line class. In this case `print(type(line1))` would return the type, but you cannot access coordinates or any attributes. That is why I used self instead of Point.

Comment: @ConfusedLearner: If that is the case, it certainly wasn't clear (to me anyway). Regardless, #2 in your answer is essentially the same as what's in mine and that is what makes the result of type(line1) be `Line` — which is what it I thought was the question.